# Getting value when Object and String cannot be added

Tags: json, jq

I have a test.json file:

```
{
"data" : [
    {
        "application" : "Microsoft Office",
        "computers" : [
            {
            "active" : true,
            "hostname" : "computer1.domain.local"
            }
        ],
        "file" : {
            "filename" : "WINWORD.EXE",
            "identity" : {
            "sha256" : "270fe88cca8156912303ebdf9481de99e4265c878cfd41964b2a94131f6c41ad"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

I can run the following command:

```
jq '.data[] | .computers[] + .file | "\(.hostname) \(.filename)"' test.json
```

Which gives me:

```
"computer1.domain.local WINWORD.EXE"
```

How can I include the value of the application key?

If I use a command such as

```
jq '.data[] | .computers[] + .application + .file | "\(.hostname) \(.application) \(.filename)"' test.json
```

I get the error:

```
jq: error (at test.json:19): object ({"active":t...) and string ("Microsoft ...) cannot be added
```

I would like an output of:

```
"computer1.domain.local Microsoft Office WINWORD.EXE"
```

Comment: Just post your "exact" expected output desired

Comment: "computer1.domain.local Microsoft Office WINWORD.EXE"

Answer (score 1):

You can add application to the constructed structure:

```
jq '.data[]
   | .computers[] + .file + {application}
   | "\(.hostname) \(.application) \(.filename)"'
```

Answer (score 0):

One technique you could employ is "expanding" the array of computers, then you could generate the results you want.

```
.computers = .computers[] | "\(.computers.hostname) \(.application) \(.file.filename)"
```

---

```
.computers = .computers[]
```

This changes the input where each item in the `computers` array is substituted in place of the array itself to something that looks like this:

```
{
  "application": "Microsoft Office",
  "computers": {
    "active": true,
    "hostname": "computer1.domain.local"
  },
  "file": {
    "filename": "WINWORD.EXE",
    "identity": {
      "sha256": "270fe88cca8156912303ebdf9481de99e4265c878cfd41964b2a94131f6c41ad"
    }
  }
}
{
  "application": "Microsoft Office",
  "computers": {
    "active": false,
    "hostname": "computer2.domain.local"
  },
  "file": {
    "filename": "WINWORD.EXE",
    "identity": {
      "sha256": "270fe88cca8156912303ebdf9481de99e4265c878cfd41964b2a94131f6c41ad"
    }
  }
}
```